# series of question duplication

Tags: discussion, support

I can see numerous amount of questions in queue which is flagged as duplicate. But how can a new question be labeled as duplicate of old one?

[Add shipping on subtotal after discount](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/19806/add-shipping-on-subtotal-after-discount)

**asked 2 years ago**

[How can i apply coupon code if order total value is greater than 100 INR?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147442/how-can-i-apply-coupon-code-if-order-total-value-is-greater-than-100-inr)

**asked 2 days ago**

same thing this review

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/close/81105

https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/close/81112

Comment: I already notified this to moderators couple of days before and honestly, it was too  annoying for me too.  I am removing user reference from this thread since it may feel bad.

Comment: @RajeevKTomy feel free to do that i am just making clear for mod.

Comment: Yes, Keep rocking brother.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The user in question has been notified about this behavior and he has been banned from the review queue.

Comment: thanks for quick action.. :)